# How did I earn this bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

There is a [fairly old C++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8425077/2069064) asking about creating new operators. After a brief intro, it asks:

> Can I create a new operator, `.*`, too? If yes, can anyone give me some guidance?

It was then bountied, with the bounty text stating:

> The current answers do not contain enough detail.
>
> Bounty will be awarded to whoever can create a simple, consolidated solution with examples, from [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/customoperators.aspx). Needs to be capable of achieving `if (blah in blah) {`

(That bounty criterion was wholly unrelated to this actual question - seems instead a question in of itself, but whatever).

When the bounty period expired, I was auto-awarded half the bounty. At this moment, my answer has 6 upvotes. [Lightness's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425207/2069064) has 23. When I posted my answer, I think that one was around 10, so at no point was mine the highest upvoted answer, and I don't think I even earned the most upvotes since the bounty started.

Per the help:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

How did I get the +25? It should go to Lightness.

Comment: Lightness' answer was posted outside the bounty period and is not eligible for auto-awarding.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer **created after the bounty started** with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Comment: And additional evidence: the [timeline of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8425077/timeline), which shows what answers with their current scores, that were posted after the bounty started, in one location. Barry wins with +6, other answers in that period have +5, +3, +1 and 0. For exact scores at the time the bounty ended, see the timelines of the posts and the reputation log for each answerer.